# Azure - AKS integration with API Manager for JWT authentication

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am trying to implement the following workflow to setup in the Azure:

1. Private AKS cluster to deploy my applications - Already provisioned
2. An ingress controller (AGIC preferably) for routing traffic to pods - Already provisioned
3. An APIM for generating JWT tokens - Not provisioned yet until I figure out it is possible

What I need is, when a user tries to access a URL (eg: test.example.de), the traffic flow should be as follows:

a. A user Hits the DNS and that DNS is routed to the Application Gateway created by the AGIC

b. Then APP Gateway, without sending the traffic to the Ingresss and then to services and pods, it SHOULD authenticate with APIM to generate a JWT token or to validate if the user has permissions.

c. If user has permissions ,the traffic will be routed to the ingress and then to the service and the pods.

d. If user doesn't have permissions, don't route the traffic

I looked into this azure doc [1], but it seems like it doesn't perform JWT authentication.

Can someone please help me?

[1] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to do exactly as you want to currently: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92829/does-agic-support-jwt-validation

APPGW cant do JWT validation, hence AGIC cant

according to the article [linked in that thread](https://medium.com/@jw_ng/using-azure-application-gateway-with-api-management-service-f9b9b2cd1731) - you can use APIM as an intermediary to do validation